# angularjs tutorial: test ERROR, no more info

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

This is my first time using Angular (and Karma), so please excuse me if this is a total beginner's question: that's what I am.

I'm trying to run the Angular-phonecat tests, as described in Step 02 - Writing and Running Tests

My code is checked out directly from the step 2 branch (`git checkout -f step-2`)

When running the test (`angular-phonecat\scripts> test`), I'm given the following message:

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.2 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 30.0.1599 (Windows 7)]: Connected on socket Jw-2z-zZ-pytGNN-SHRM
Chrome 30.0.1599 (Windows 7): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.472 secs / 0 secs)
```

There is no more information given, and I cannot find any log the would detail the problem (nothing in /test or its sub-directories, nor in /logs).  I also cannot find a log for karma in general - is there one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i started today with angular and karma aswell, im on a mac and i have the same problem.
I joined the IRC channel #angularjs at freenode and asked for some help and this is the answer that i got.

```
[16:59] <Wirde> Hi, I just started with the Angular-phonecat tutorial, after installing karma and the adapters I got too step 2 but when I try to run the unit tests it gives me the error: Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.327 secs / 0 secs). Can some please tell me whats wrong?
[17:00] <dmco> Wirde: I think phonecat is wonky after some 1.2rcX upgrades
[17:01] <dmco> Wirde: Another guy was complaining about issues with it yesterday
[17:02] <Wirde> dmco: hi, thanks for the answer, how do you suggest i proceed? Is there another good way to learn about karma and testing with angular?
[17:02] <rdepena> http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/01/full-spectrum-testing-with-angularjs-and-karma.html#karma
[17:02] <dmco> Wirde: One easy way would be to scaffold a new project using Yeoman and the AngularJS generator
[17:02] <rdepena> this is a great source
[17:02] <dmco> ^^ Wirde that is a good link too
[17:03] <Wirde> dmco: rdepena: Thank you for the help! I will check it out :D
```

Not sure if this is the response that you wanted or if its enought but i tought i might share it.

Comment: I ended up skipping testing and running into another error (step 7 - routing).  Replacing angular.js with the stable 1.08 fixed both issues.  Thanks!  I can't imagine why they replaced the old angular in the tutorial with new if it isn't supported...

Answer (score 5):

You need to add this line to karma.conf.js

```
exclude: ['app/lib/angular/angular-scenario.js'],
```

Theres an issue relating to this problem here: https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/issues/71